# Azure spring boot : PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory

I have spring boot azure cloud active directory application , when am running the app locally getting below error. Can you please someone help?

> org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException:
> An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Couldn't
> retrieve remote JWK set:
> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
> GET request for
> "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my_tenant_id>/discovery/v2.0/keys":
> PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target     at
> org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:104)
> ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]     at
> org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:88)
> ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]     at
> org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182)
> ~[spring-security-core-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]   at
> org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:134)
> ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]     at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:68)
> ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]    at
> org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.instrument.web.TraceWebServletConfiguration$LazyTracingFilter.doFilter(TraceWebServletConfiguration.java:131)
> ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-autoconfigure-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
> ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.tomcat.TraceValve.invoke(TraceValve.java:103)
> ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]    at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.71.jar:9.0.71]    at
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]   Caused by:
> org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtException: An error
> occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Couldn't retrieve remote
> JWK set: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O
> error on GET request for
> "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my_tenant_id>/discovery/v2.0/keys":
> PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target     at
> org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.createJwt(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:169)
> ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]    at
> org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.decode(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:137)
> ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]    at
> org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:97)
> ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]     ... 64
> common frames omitted      Caused by:
> com.nimbusds.jose.RemoteKeySourceException: Couldn't retrieve remote
> JWK set: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O
> error on GET request for
> "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my_tenant_id>/discovery/v2.0/keys":
> PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target     at
> com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.RemoteJWKSet.updateJWKSetFromURL(RemoteJWKSet.java:307)
> ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.22.jar:9.22]  at
> com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.RemoteJWKSet.get(RemoteJWKSet.java:437)
> ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.22.jar:9.22]  at
> com.nimbusds.jose.proc.JWSVerificationKeySelector.selectJWSKeys(JWSVerificationKeySelector.java:157)
> ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.22.jar:9.22]  at
> com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.selectKeys(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:283)
> ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.22.jar:9.22]  at
> com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:354)
> ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.22.jar:9.22]  at
> com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:303)
> ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.22.jar:9.22]  at
> org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.createJwt(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:154)
> ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]    ... 66 common frames
> omitted    Caused by: java.io.IOException:
> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
> GET request for
> "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my_tenant_id>/discovery/v2.0/keys":
> PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target     at
> org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder$JwkSetUriJwtDecoderBuilder$RestOperationsResourceRetriever.getResponse(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:448)
> ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]    at
> org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder$JwkSetUriJwtDecoderBuilder$RestOperationsResourceRetriever.retrieveResource(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:435)
> ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]    at
> com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.RemoteJWKSet.updateJWKSetFromURL(RemoteJWKSet.java:305)
> ~[nimbus-jose-jwt-9.22.jar:9.22]  ... 72 common frames omitted
> Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O
> error on GET request for
> "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my_tenant_id>/discovery/v2.0/keys":
> PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target     at
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:791)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:666)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder$JwkSetUriJwtDecoderBuilder$RestOperationsResourceRetriever.getResponse(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:445)
> ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.7.6.jar:5.7.6]    ... 74 common frames
> omitted    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path
> building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target     at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:353)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:296)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:291)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:183)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1507)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1417)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:456)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:427)
> ~[na:na]  at
> org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
> ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]   at
> org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
> ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]   at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
> ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]   at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
> ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]   at
> org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
> ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]   at
> org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
> ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]   at
> org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
> ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]   at
> org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
> ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]   at
> org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
> ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]   at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
> ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]   at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
> ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]   at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
> ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]   at
> org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:87)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:109)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.client.MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.intercept(MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.java:86)
> ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]   at
> org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.mvc.TracingClientHttpRequestInterceptor.intercept(TracingClientHttpRequestInterceptor.java:69)
> ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]    at
> org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.LazyTraceClientHttpRequestInterceptor.intercept(LazyTraceClientHttpRequestInterceptor.java:51)
> ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]    at
> org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:77)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   at
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:782)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]   ... 76 common frames omitted     Caused
> by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building
> failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
> unable to find valid certification path to requested target   at
> java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1341)
> ~[na:na]  ... 112 common frames omitted Caused by:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target     at
> java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
> ~[na:na]  ... 118 common frames omitted

Comment: am using open jdk 11

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add a certificate to your cacerts file. Different versions of java can have different cacerts.

In regards to Azure Active Directory you could follow the documentation on "Trust WSO2 Identity Server": https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/configuring-azure-active-directory-to-trust-wso2-identity-server/#configuring-azure-ad

Otherwise, you could try to download and manually add the certificate to cacerts.

To export the HTTPS certificate in Firefox, click on the lock icon next to the URL address, then select **"More Info" > "Security" > "Show Certificate" > "Details" > "Export".**

In Chrome, click on the site icon to the left of the address in the address bar, then select **"Certificate" > "Details" > "Export".**

You could also find some insights on this question: ["PKIX path building failed" and "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ/36427118#36427118)

Another great resource: https://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed/

Comment: Tried the above solution, but did not work.

Comment: Try updating your SSL certificate: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-ssl-update